# Stating the induction hypothesis

Tags: soft-question, proof-writing, induction

I would like to ask about the best way to state the induction hypothesis in a proof by induction.

Just to use a concrete example, suppose I wanted to prove that $n!\ge 2^{n-1}$ for every positive integer $n$.

Assuming that I have already verified the case $n=1$, which of the following statements of the induction hypothesis would be best to use, and, more importantly, are any of them unacceptable?

1) Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ with $n!\ge2^{n-1}$.

2) Let $n!\ge2^{n-1}$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

3) Assume that $n!\ge2^{n-1}$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

4) Let $k!\ge2^{k-1}$.

(I realize that this is partly a matter of taste and style, and please note that I am not asking how to finish the inductive step.)

Comment: I'd go with (3).

Comment: I would also take (3)... So it is clear that it is the premise of the induction step...

Comment: I would strongly avoid 3). To me it says assume there exists an $n$ such that $\dots$.  Then $n$ has been quantified away and is no longer free.  Something like suppose that $k$ is a natural number such that $\dots$ seems fine.

Comment: It is important to have the word "assume", so (3). The other ones are somewhat confusing since "let" could lead the reader to think it is sufficient to find one value of $n$ or $k$ satisfying the inequality.

Comment: The inductive hypothesis is an assumption not a definition so (3) is the best way to state it, but you don't want to have the "for some" bit. You just want to assume $n! \ge 2^{n-1}$.

Comment: I would go with (3) except, as Andre suggests, you should not overload the meaning of $n$. It is a free variable in the statement of your proposition, and you use it again to refer to a specific value where you assume the inequality holds. It would be better to replace $n$ with $k$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I appreciate the feedback from you and the other commenters as well, especially since 3) is the version I have used for many years, until I recently switched to 1).  Let me ask you two follow-up questions which were brought up in the comments:  a) Is it preferable to use k rather than n in the inductive hypothesis?  b) Is it  better to use  "Assume that k is ..." or "Suppose that k is ..."  rather than "Let k be ..."?

Comment: In teaching this sort of thing for many years, I developed a preference for $k$. in the belief that it diminishes confusion.  But I must acknowledge that I have no "experimental" evidence that it does.  In the earliest examples, I use a specific $k$, such as $k=1$ then $k=2$ then $k=17$.  For b) I have no opinion. Early on I use something like "is good" instead of the more abstract looking $P(k)$.

Comment: Thanks for your reply -- this was helpful!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Principle of Mathematical Induction says that for all "properties" $P$,
$$\left(P(0)\land\forall k\in \mathbb N\left(P(k) \implies P(k+1)\right)\right)\implies \forall n\in \mathbb N(P(n)).$$

So you're basically asking how to write the $\forall k\in \mathbb N\left(P(k)\implies P(k+1)\right)$ bit.

It's a universal statement. It's common to start those by "Let $k\in \mathbb N$". Then you want to prove the conditional statement $P(k)\implies P(k+1)$. It's common to prove these by starting with "suppose $P(k)$ holds" (or some variation).

Wrapping it up, I'd write "Let $k\in \mathbb N$ and suppose that $P(k)$" or "Let $k\in \mathbb N$ be such that $P(k)$ holds" or some variation of this. This includes (1) and to some extent (4). I wouldn't use (2) or (3) because the word "some" strongly suggests existential quantification which isn't even present in the formulation of the Principle of Mathematical Induction used in this answer (which is the most common anyway).